# Sawtooth shaped ping

Tags: networking

I moved to a new place and over here, I'm getting much worse internet speeds than I should. It was ok for the first day, around 40-60Mbps but the second and third day it dropped to 5-6ish, every now and then though, it returns to good speed for a few minutes.

I pinged a server a few hundred times and noticed a kind of sawtooth pattern in the ping times. It starts with 5ms, then gradually grows to ~300 and then drops to 5 again, over and over. I've seen this before, a few years ago in another apartment I was living in. I don't recall ever figuring out the cause though, at some point it just disappeared.

Anybody know what might be causing this?

Comment: What kind of device/OS are you using and have you tried a `traceroute`/`tracert`?  Have you tested another device to see if it is also affected?

Comment: also, what is your connection? LTE? Wi-Fi? Copper Ethernet? Direct fiber channel to an FX NIC?

Answer (score 2):

Sawtooth shaped ping time graphs for Wi-Fi devices can be caused by 802.11 power save mode. You probably won't see the sawtooth if you set the ping interval to a tenth of a second instead of once per second.

Note that the issue I'm talking about is benign. It only happens when you have very little traffic going on, like once-per-second pings. A real web page load or video stream or download would be a lot more traffic and not show the latency graph sawtooth.